# SSL for bitnami CouchDB hosted on AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, openssl, couchdb

I've created a instance with CouchDB from bitnami. Here is the link
`https://bitnami.com/stack/couchdb`

it is working fine on HTTP. But I want to make it work on https, for that , I used this guide to create a self signed certification :
`https://docs.bitnami.com/oci/infrastructure/couchdb/administration/create-ssl-certificate-couchdb/`

and their guide to enable it on server:
`https://docs.bitnami.com/oci/infrastructure/couchdb/administration/enable-ssl/`

This is my section of SSL in `/opt/bitnami/couchdb/etc/local.ini`

```
`[ssl]
port = 6984
enable = true
cert_file = /opt/bitnami/couchdb/etc/server.crt
key_file = /opt/bitnami/couchdb/etc/server.key
;password = somepassword
; set to true to validate peer certificates
;verify_ssl_certificates = false
; Set to true to fail if the client does not send a certificate. Only used if verify_ssl_certificates is true.
;fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
; Path to file containing PEM encoded CA certificates (trusted
; certificates used for verifying a peer certificate). May be omitted if
; you do not want to verify the peer.
;cacert_file = /full/path/to/cacertf
; The verification fun (optional) if not specified, the default
; verification fun will be used.
;verify_fun = {Module, VerifyFun}
; maximum peer certificate depth
;ssl_certificate_max_depth = 1`
```

Please let me know what other information I should be giving. Thanks in advance I've been wrapping my head around this for a week now!

this is log from curl -a -k mydomain.com

```
`* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55b57b804f50)
*   Trying 3.85.5.117...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55b57b804f50)
* Connected to data.posifier.com (3.85.5.117) port 6984 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to data.posifier.com:6984
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to data.posifier.com:6984`
```

Comment: Same issue, did you solve it ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Basically, after weeks of trying everything, I used Nginx to reverse proxy to couch port. This is by far the easiest solution that even worked. I followed this guide: `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04`, Just change your operating system on this post. Let me know if you need further help 
(I used this tutorial to set Nginx with SSL on AWS)

Comment: I've found a solution, no need to use Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

In order to SSL to work properly you need to have (at least) a self-signed certificate. In your config file you have the line cacert_file = /full/path/to/cacertf commented.

I wrote a step by step guide to make it work.

Take a look [here](https://medium.com/hacking-info-sec/how-to-install-couchdb-with-ssl-f0040bebb6d9)